# Using data from XMLParser while building static XML using MarkupBuilder

Tags: groovy

I want to include data retrieved from an XMLParser and build a new file using the MarkupBuilder.

I'm having trouble figuring out how this would work.

**C:/file.xml:**

```
<externalData>
  <data><nestedData><soOnAndSoForth/></nestedData></data>      
</externalData>
```

**Code.groovy:**

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer).'root'("id":"foo") {

    File content = new File("C:/file.xml")

    def externalFile = new XmlParser(false,true,true).parse(content)
    // may or may not modify this external data...

    externalFile.each { elem -> ${elem} } 
    'moreData'('id':'myData')
}
println writer.toString()
```

**Expected result:**

```
<root id="foo">
    <externalData>
         <data><nestedData><soOnAndSoForth/></nestedData></data>     
    </externalData>
    <moreData id="myData">
</root>
```

**What I get:**

```
<root id="foo">
  <$ />
  <moreData id="myData">
</root>
```

Edit: if I'm taking the wrong approach here, such as not using MarkupBuilder and using something else, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Bumping, still not sure the right route to go...

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226886/importing-in-xml-from-a-file-while-using-markupbuilder), you can solve this using StreamingMarkupBuilder and XmlSlurper.

If you need to stay with MarkupBuilder the following does a verbatim insert into your xml stream:

```
import groovy.xml.* 

def serialize = { xml -> 
  def sw = new StringWriter()
  new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(sw)).print(xml)
  sw.toString()
}

def writer = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder(writer).'root'("id":"foo") {
    def otherXml = new XmlParser(false,true,true).parse(new File('file.xml'))
    // may or may not modify this external data...
    mkp.yieldUnescaped("\n  " + serialize(otherXml).readLines().join("\n  "))
    'moreData'('id':'myData')
}
println writer.toString()
```

where just:

```
mkp.yieldUnescaped(serialize(otherXml))
```

would have been enough if we didn't care about formatting.

The above prints out:

```
<root id='foo'>
  <externalData>
    <data>
      <nestedData>
        <soOnAndSoForth/>
      </nestedData>
    </data>
  </externalData>
  <moreData id='myData' />
</root>
```

We use XmlNodePrinter instead of XmlUtil.serialize to get rid of the xml declaration line. `mkp.yieldUnescaped` inserts a string verbatim into your xml.

I wouldn't call this pretty or robust, but I think it does the job.